# Forward private ip to public ip

Tags: networking

I have 2 machines

Machine A have two interfaces and webserver

eth0 is private ip 192.168.1.1
eth1 is public ip  1.2.3.4

Machine B
eth0 is private ip 192.168.1.2 running tomcat(8080)

Now how can i access 192.168.1.2:8080 using my public ip

Any idea how to port forward this?

---

Thank you guys for your answers. I know how to use reverse proxy since my public ip contain a django application which run on port 8000. But my question is , is it possible to act my machine A as router of machine B.  that will accept connection on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for the **reverse-proxy** module of Apache.

[Here is a howto](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Apache2_reverse_proxies), [and the official doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_proxy.html). There are plenty of docs on the net.

This is also possible with nginx.

Regarding Tomcat application, also look [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html), as you probably want to tell Tomcat what its public address is.

Answer (score 0):

SSH tunnel works, run in machine A:

```
ssh -f -L 3000:192.168.1.2:8080 localhost -N
```

You can change 3000 to 8080 (or any other port) if it not used by machine A.

Any connection to `192.168.1.1:3000` or `1.2.3.4:3000` will be forwarded to `192.168.1.2:8080`.